# template method within template - instance declaration and class method declaration signature differs

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a templated class and with in that class a further templated method. The templated method requires a different  non-explicit but standard typename as shown in the Class and method declaration below.

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:

    // constructors
    Matrix(int  rows, int cols,T _initial);

    Matrix():mCols(0),mRows(0),mdata(0)
    {   }
    Matrix(int rows,int cols, 
           std::vector<T>&X):mRows(rows),mCols(cols),mdata(X)
    { }
    int get_numofrows(); // returns  mRows
    int get_numofcols()  // returns mCols
   void show_matrix();  // prints matrix on console, which is really the vector <T> mdata

    template<typename E> // <----focus is here
    Matrix<E> convert_Matrix(); // <----and here

    // other  methods not relevant to this problem go here
    // ....

private:

    int mRows;
    int mCols;
    std::vector<T> mdata;
};
```

the implementation details of method `convert_Matrix()` is shown below:

```
template<T>
template<E>
Matrix<E> Matrix<T>::convert_Matrix()
{ 
    // creates a vector cast of all elements of underlying
    // vector of type T to vector elements of type E
    // eg; vector<E> D uses vector copy constructor

    std::vector<E> D(this->mdata.begin(), this->mdata.end());

    // uses vector D as an argument to create the rest of the matrix

    Matrix<E> MX(this->get_numofrows(),this->get_numofcols(),D);
    return MX;
}
```

Intuitively it would seem that the instances in main that use this method (`convert_Matrix()`) should compile and link but complains of substitution/deduction errors on E only when the convert_Matrix() method is  invoked by an instance. It compiles without incident if the method instance is not called in main.

The following code was was developed to test the method `convert_Matrix()`:

```
#include " Matrix.h"

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> Mz = {
        139.342, 144.167,149.543,153.678,155.987,155.21,155.23,155.876,
        144.112,151.34,153.6789,156.34,159.0124,156.678,156.56,156.6543,
        150.456,155.123,160.45,163.876,158.432,156.78,156.123,156.525,
        159.567,161.267,162.567,160.67,160.59,159.001,159.675,159.456,
        159.876,160.743,161.456,162.432,162.876,155.543,155.123,155.840,
        161.111,161.222,161.333,161.678,160.543,157.890,157.1212,157.987,
        162.111,162.222,161.333,163.987,162.888,157.543,157.666,157.345,
        162.234,162.777,161.888,161.444,163.99,158.775,158.234,158.98
    };
    Matrix<float> FF(8,8,Mz);
    // Matrix<int>BV = FF.convert_Matrix(); <--deduction/substitution error couldn't deduce E
    Matrix<int>BV = FF.convert_Matrix<int>();// <---works
    BV.show_Matrix();
    FF.show_Matrix();
}
```

I was successful in getting the  code above to compile and execute with an instance instantiation of `FF.convert_Matrix` as shown above but I am not sure if this approach and definition is syntactically accurate. I tried many more type conversions and they all seemed to compile and link and execute correctly without incident (substituting the appropriate type in place of `int`)
which leads me to the following questions

1) I can understand from a logical perspective, that if the compiler linker complains about type deduction I should try to help it. I tried `auto`, I tried `decltype`,
 I tried combinations of both, why did the approach I used work? And why didn't the straight forward approach (e.g. class declaration) not work?

2) I stumbled upon this solution illustrated above, by trial and error. Is there some sort of rule in the ISO standard that defines what I did?

3) Is there a better way to do the same thing? Why is the method signature in the class definition, different signature then when it is instantiated in an instance?

4) I do not think this solution issue is best served by a specialization and more code. The solution I stumbled upon works, so why add more code?
I would rather just change the minimum in class declaration and implementation semantics for clarity

Any comments you have or alternate solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not look at the type on the left side of an assignment to deduce template parameters.  What the compiler sees is `FF.convert_Matrix()`, and it is unable to deduce the template parameter for `convert_Matrix`.  This is why you need to explicitly specify the template parameter.

The standard library's [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get), when used to extract a value from a tuple based on type, also needs to have the type explicitly specified.